# Wildcard nested selector

Tags: css, sass

I have the following bit of Sass code :

```
.c-panel-menu-c {
    &.grid_6 {
        float: right;
    }
}
```

i need to have float right applied to all grids that start with grid_ . The float should only be set when the grid class is applied to an element that also has c-panel-menu-c.

I wanted to use a wildcard selector like

```
div[class*='grid_'] {
    float:right
}
```

But am not sure if it's possible the way i need it. Something like

```
.c-panel-menu-c {
    &.div[class*='grid_'] {
        vertical-align: top;
    }
}
```

Which doesnt work.

Thank you for any tips/advice.

Comment: I think you have an extra `.` in there..shouldn't it be `div[class*='grid_']` without the period/full stop?

Comment: Do you need single quotes in `&.div[class*='grid_']`?

Comment: Thanks for replies. I'm getting '... may only be used at the beginning of a  compound selector' when trying &div[class*='grid_']{float:right;}. adding a space between & and div doesnt do anything

Comment: What "doesn't work"?  Is it generating the wrong selector?

Comment: The wildcard selector inside c-panel-menu-c is not applying float:right to any class that starts with grid_

Comment: "It doesn't work in my browser" is a really bad way of debugging Sass, you have to look at the compiled result to see if it is generating what you expected.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

the problem is the tag name ... you can not concatenate a tag name, for example `div`, at the end of another selector, like you would with a class name. Let's look at your example:

```
.c-panel-menu-c {
  &.grid_6 {
    ...
  }
}
```

will return

```
.c-panel-menu-c.grid_6 { ... }
```

which is a valid selector. But attaching 'div' at the end (lets leave out the attribute selector part for now)

```
.c-panel-menu-c {
  &div {
    ...
  }
}
```

does not make sense (and it also isn't possible in Sass, hence you get an error) as the tag name should always be before the class or id selector. This does not change if we add an attribute selector statement, so that's why it does not work the way you tried `&div[class*='grid_']`.

What you can do, is add the attribute selector directly to the preceding class name, like so:

```
.c-panel-menu-c {
    &[class*='grid_'] {
        ...
    }
}
```

which would compile to:

```
.c-panel-menu-c[class=*'grid_'] { ... }
```

and select everything that has the class `.c-panel-menu-c` and a class containing with `grid_`.